# Mount OpenMediaVault NFS in docker-compose.yml volume for Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, nfs, openmediavault

I am trying to externalise my runtime data from my applications to be saved in OpenMediaVault shared folder.
I was able to create shared folder and configure NFS or at least I think so. The config I see in `OMV/Services/NFS/Shares` is:

```
Shared folder: NasFolder[on /dev/sda1, nas/]
Client: 192.168.50.0/24
Privelage: Read/Write
Extra options: subtree_check,insecure
```

Now in that shared folder I have this structure(I checked it using windows SMB/CIFS config)

```
\\nfs-ip\NasFolder
          |- mysql
          |   \- some my sql folders...
          |- TEST.txt
```

I want to use this `mysql` folder to store MariaDB runtime data(I know names are messed up I am in a middle of a migration to Maria...). And meaby create some other folders for other services. This is my config from `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: arm64v8/mariadb:latest
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    restart: on-failure:3
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: nfs-volume
        target: /mysql
        volume:
          nocopy: true
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw
    command: --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_general_ci

volumes:
  nfs-volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: addr=192.168.50.70,nolock,soft,rw
      device: ":/NasFolder"
```

Now when I run `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml --with-registry-auth maprealm` on my manager node I get error on `maprealm_mysqldb.1` that looks like this:

```
"Err": "starting container failed: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/maprealm_nfs-volume/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount :/NasFolder:/var/lib/docker/volumes/maprealm_nfs-volume/_data, data: addr=192.168.50.70,nolock,soft: permission denied",
```

I am pretty new to integration stuff. This is my home server and I just can't find good tutorials that 'get through my thick skull' how to configure those NFS paths and permissions or at least how can I debug it beside just getting this error. I know that `volumes.nfs-volume.driver_opts.device` is supposed to be a path but I am not sure what path should that be.
I was trying to adapt config from here: https://gist.github.com/ruanbekker/4a9c0d250bce9f84482f2a788ce92131

Edit1) Few additional details:

- Docker swarm has 3 nodes and only one node is manager with availability pause.
- OMV is running on a separet machine that is not a part of a cluster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so if someone would be looking for solution:

1. OMV by default has `/export/` for NFS so volume needed to be updated. I needed to update volume for mysql and update `volumes.mysql-volume.driver_opts.device` to include that `/export/` prefix and I also added path to `mysql` folder to have volume for `mysqldb` service use only:

```
volumes:
  mysql-volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: addr=192.168.50.70,nolock,soft,rw
      device: ":/export/NasFolder/mysql"
```

2. After those changes there was need to update volume config on mysql/mariadb:

```
  mysqldb:
    image: arm64v8/mariadb:latest
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    restart: on-failure:3
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: mysql-volume
        target: /var/lib/mysql
        volume:
          nocopy: true
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw
    command: --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

`mysqldb.volumes.source` points to name of your volume defined in step 1 - `mysql-volume`
`mysqldb.volumes.target` is where inside container runtime data is stored. In mysql/mariadb databases runtime data is stored in `/var/lib/mysql` so you want to point to that and you can only use full path.

3. Since I used default OMV config there were problems with permissions. So I updated `OMV/Services/NFS/Shares` to this:

```
Shared folder: NasFolder[on /dev/sda1, nas/]
#here you can see note 'The location of the files to share. The share will be accessible at /export/.'
Client: 192.168.50.0/24
Privelage: Read/Write
Extra options: rw,sync,no_root_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,no_acl
```